# Implement Sync functionality for SQL server 2012 DB

Tags: android, sql-server, synchronization

I am working on android app which will provide work in offline mode capability. I am storing data in SQLite DB using Content Providers. 
NOw I want to implement sync functionality for my app. Which will enable syncing data once client becomes online again. 
Can anyone please provide me any good example on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in the past. What I ended up was designing an xml packet format to use while communicating with a web service on the server. This packet contained header information with user id, device id, date/time, GPS cords and a mode defining what type of data is contained within the packet.

Any packets to send to the server from the device are written out to a folder on the device and a background process then sends them once a connection is available and only upon a successful received response from the server are they removed from the folder on the device.

For getting updated information from the server I created a sync generation number for each user account and anytime something is done on the server that could impact what data the user/device should have I increment the number. The phone then polls the server (at whatever interval you want) and just checks this number against what it was the last time it sync'd. If the number is the same then you are done (with minimal data transfer) if the number is different then the device requests any/all new data required (how you do this will depend on the type of data you are wanting). Only upon successfully loading the updated data do I update the sync generation number on the device. This way if the connection drops out it will re-request the data the next time it goes online.

I haven't used direct push yet but there are quite a few examples on how to setup something like that on the web. SignalR is one possible way I've been looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But for syncing, what needs to be done at server side? For example, I have SQL server DB at the server side ...Should I implement REST APIs ? If so, then how do we sync only updated data? Is there any available tools that we can use?

Comment: I built a web service in asp .net (using a REST approach) this web service then sits between the web (devices) and the SQL db. In here is where you need to develop some logic for handling the syncing of data.